# Axiomatization of field theory for the Knuth-Bendix algorithm?

Tags: logic, field-theory, soft-question, computer-science

Is there an axiomatization of [Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) suitable for the [Knuth-Bendix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Bendix_completion_algorithm)? If not, would the creation of such an axiomatization be of publishable academic interest?

Comment: What does it mean for an axiomatization to be suitable for the Knuth-Bendix algorithm?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Thanks for writing. To be suitable for the Knuth-Bendix algorithm, the axiomatization must be stated strictly as a set of equations over terms in the language of classical first-order logic. The problem is the multiplicative inverse: it has the condition that the zero element is excluded, and conditionals aren't allowed.

Comment: Oh, I see! "Suitable for the Knuth-Bendix algorithm" is a rather obscure way of saying this. This is usually called an "equational axiomatization". And it is well-known that the class of fields does *not* admit an equational axiomatization.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: thanks for your reply. Could you provide a reference? Thanks

Comment: Can I give you a one sentence proof instead? Any equationally axiomatized class is closed under direct products, but the direct product of fields is not a field. Alternatively: any equationally axiomatized class contains a one-element algebra (in which all terms are equal), but there is no field with one element.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: If you'd like to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer to the question.

Comment: Ok, I've expanded my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, you clarify that by an axiomatization of field theory suitable for the Knuth-Bendix algorithm, you mean a set of first-order sentences, each of which is a (universally quantified) equation between terms.

Such an axiomatization / theory is usually called an *equational axiomatization* or *equational theory*. Equational theories, or rather their classes of models (such a class is called a [variety of algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra))) are the main objects of study in [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra).

It is well-known that the class of fields does not admit an equational axiomatization. Why? Any variety of algebras is closed under substructures, products, and homomorphic images (i.e. quotients by congruences). In fact, the [HSP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Birkhoff's_theorem) says that a class of structues (in a language with constants and function symbols, no relation symbols) is a variety of algebras if and only if it is closed under substructures, products, and homomorphic images.

Fields (as structures in the language $\{+,-,\times,0,1\}$) fail to be closed under all three of these operations:

- $\mathbb{Z}$ is a substructure of $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is a not a field.
- The product $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is not a field.
- The zero ring $\{0\}$ is a homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Q}$ (by the map sending every element of $\mathbb{Q}$ to $0$), but it is not a field.

You might hope to give an equational axiomatization of fields in a different language. For example, if you add a symbol $^{-1}$ for multiplicative inverse and decide by convention that $0^{-1} = 0$, then any substructure of a field is a field. But in this language, fields still fail to be closed under products and homomorphic images. The smallest variety of algebras containing the fields in this language is called the class of [meadows](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0823).

In fact, the goal of giving an equational axiomatization of the class of fields, even in some non-standard language, is doomed to fail. The reason is that any variety of algebras contains the one-point algebra in which all terms are equal (and hence all axioms are satisfied). But there is no field with one element (well, except in a [quite different very non-literal sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element)).